# Did I set this up correctly?

Tags: python, django

I'm asking if I set up the create method up correctly. Or does it need to be added for the other two models as well? How would this be changed?

```
class PointModel(models.Model):
    x       = models.IntegerField()
    y       = models.IntegerField()
    index           = models.IntegerField()

class DatetimeRangeModel(models.Model):
    start_datetime  = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    end_datetime    = models.CharField(max_length=14)

class PlanModel(models.Model):
    data_number             = models.IntegerField()
    data_datetime_range     = models.ForeignKey(DatetimeRangeModel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    data_polygon            = models.ForeignKey(PointModel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, data_number, data_datetime_range, data_polygon):
        plan = cls(data_number=data_number, data_datetime_range = data_datetime_range,
                    data_polygon=data_polygon)

        return plan
```

EDIT: I change the structure which fixed the undefined and added some logic that prevents the PlanModel from being deleted with the "blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL"

Does this look right?

Comment: F' all of you people who gave me down votes! This was a good question that really helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the docs for [creating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model)

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, title):
    book = cls(title=title)
    # do something with the book
    return book
```

there's no much reason to add those unless you have something to add there on the `# do something with the book` line

EDIT: instead of calling `create` you're usually do:

```
plan = PlanModel(data_number=1, ....)
plan.save()
```

or sometimes:

```
plan = PlanModel()
plan.data_number=1
...
plan.save()
```

Comment: wait that is not the case! I got errors saying the create method no longer exists...

Comment: Do I still need the create method? because removing it broke the code

Comment: you are not supposed to call `create` to create model objects, I'll update my answer

Comment: I do, I call PlanModel.create( ... data here ... ).save() and it tells me there is not attribute create

Comment: ah, let me try this out!